# Can I reload a save that has been overwritten? 

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Is it at all possible to reload overwritten saves on the Xbox 360 console when it comes to worlds on Minecraft Xbox 360 edition? I have a world which has been autosaved over and I would like the previous save to be recovered. How do I do so?

Comment: I very much doubt it

Comment: Why has this question been down voted? It is a good question as data is rarely lost when "deleted/overwritten". If it is due to the original question being poorly written then they should have either edited it or commented with suggestions to improve it.

Answer (score 4):

Popular modern filesystems will not go out of their way to actually overwrite the data on the disk or securely delete it when overwriting a file. It is therefore theoretically possible to restore the overwritten file if the stars are right (no blocks were overwritten since the file was deleted/overwritten). However, there aren't any utilities that run on an Xbox that could do this, and hooking up an Xbox HDD to a PC and finding software that will work with its proprietary FS may be more (legal) trouble than it is worth.

Sometimes it is best to cut your losses and move on.